# which lifecycle hooks correspond to ionViewDidLoad and ionViewWillUnload in ionic5

Tags: ionic3, ionic5

I am updating my ionic 3 project to ionic 5.
The lifecycle in ionic 5 has slightly difference comparing to ionic 3. I cannot find ionViewDidLoad and ionViewWillUnload.
Can you plelase tell which lifecycle hooks correspond to ionViewDidLoad and ionViewWillUnload in ionic5?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Events like ionViewDidLoad and ionViewWillUnload are now removed in Ionic 5.
You can use `ionViewDidEnter` and `ionViewDidLeave`. You can find more info about ionic lifecycle events [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)